# How to get count value in laravel 5.6 blade?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to show the count according to rta_id and deleted_at..I have rta_id and deleted_at column in issuer table.

```
<?php 
    $issuer = DB::table('issuer')
                ->where(['rta_id'=> $rtaData->rta_id])
                ->get(); 
?>
    <td style="text-align: center;">
        <a href="{{ url('/admin/view-issuer/'.$rtaData->rta_id ) }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-mini" >
            {{ count($issuer) }}
    </td>
```

This is my code. i have displayed the count value according to rta_id but i also want to show count value according to deleted_at when it is null means only count the rows where the deleted_at is equals to NULL.

Please help to count the rows according ton rta_id and deleted_at value in the same query....

Comment: You shouldn't have PHP logic in your blade templates. Figure it out in a controller, send those results to blade.

Comment: Is this written in blade?

Comment: _Small Point_ You seem to be missing a `</a>` tag

Answer (score 0):

In controller get those records having deleted_at = null like shown below and send to view.

```
$issuer= DB::table('issuer')->where(['rta_id'=> $rtaData->rta_id])->where('deleted_at',null)->get();
```

then in blade view

```
{{count($issuer)}}
```

Comment: I think it's an overkill to get the whole recordset in order tho show the number of records. You should do in on SQL/ORM level.

Answer (score 0):

Use Count eloquent

```
$count = DB::table('issuer')
            ->where('rta_id', '=', $rtaData->rta_id)
            ->where('deleted_at', '=', null)
            ->count();
```

And you need to add this lines in your controller and then send it in your view using `compact`

In your blade

```
<td style="text-align: center;">
    <a href="{{ url('/admin/view-issuer/'.$rtaData->rta_id ) }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-mini" >
        {{ $issuer }} 
    </a>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this

```
<?php 
    $issuer = DB::table('issuer')
            ->where(['rta_id'=> $rtaData->rta_id])
            ->where('deleted_at', null)
            ->count(); 
?>
<td style="text-align: center;">
    <a href="{{ url('/admin/view-issuer/'.$rtaData->rta_id ) }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-mini" >
        {{ $issuer }}</a>
</td>
```